# Zsh function for checking for duplicate PATH entries and for occluded executables

Tags: security, path, zsh

This occurs on many systems and I expect someone has a solution for it.

The PATH environment variable is a major part of security issues.  For sanity's sake, the path portion of the `.zshrc` looks like:

```
# Set Path
PATH_RUBY="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3..0/bin"
PATH_TREESITTER="$HOME/p/na/ts/tree_sitter_na/node_modules/.bin"
PATH_CONDA="/usr/local/anaconda3/bin"
PATH_CARGO=".cargo/bin"
PATH_TEX="/usr/texbin:/opt/X11/bin"
PATH_HOME="$HOME/bin:$HOME"
PATH_OSX="/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library
/Apple/usr/bin"
export PATH="$PATH_RUBY:$PATH_CONDA:$PATH_TREESITTER:$PATH_CARGO:$PATH_TEX:$PATH_HOME:$PATH_OSX"
```

While I can check the path munging to be sure that no full directory is repeated in the path, is there a function anyone has written to list of conflicts?  I am trying to guard against some unchecked installation of a tool like `TreeSitter` having its own `ssh` command, which would execute instead of the later `/usr/bin/ssh`.   This tool would both add to security and also untangle badly done installations.

That is, I want a tool like:

```
$ checkpath
.../p/na/tree_sitter_na/node_modules/.bin/ssh occudes /usr/bin/ssh
$
```

Comment: What you want is not exactly clear. You already have a way of making sure that each directory is only added to `$PATH` once and then you want to see if there is a binary or executable of the same name that appears in multiple locations. If this is a system that you manage and where you have sudoer rights, then you can simply `su` to the user and run whereis if you are looking for a specific executable or if that's too tedious,use a tool like `printf` on the listed directories to send their contents to `stdout` which can then be parsed for duplicates.

Comment: Writing the tool is a doable project.   A quick and dirty approach, would be "ls for all directories in $PATH | sort | uniq" and then do work to print nice errors.   I was seeing if this already was written somewhere. :)

Comment: Could you point out what is not clear?   I want a list of occluded executables and what is executed instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `zsh`, `type -a` will list all occurrences of a command in the `PATH`.  The first one in the list is the 'active' match:

```bash
> type -a pwd
pwd is a shell builtin
pwd is /bin/pwd
> cp /bin/ls ~/bin
> type -a ls
ls is /bin/ls
ls is /Users/gairfowl/bin
```

More info [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9683/which-but-all).

---

There are some very useful features in `zsh` to help manipulate paths. With 'tied' variables, the executable search path can be referenced via either the `PATH` scalar or the `path` array:

```bash
> print $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin
> path+=/sbin
> print $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/sbin
> print -l $path
/usr/bin
/bin
/sbin
```

`PATH` and `path` are set up this way by default. Other variables can be configured as tied variables, e.g. `typeset -T LD_LIBRARY_PATH ld_library_path`.

The `-U` option to `typeset` can be used to set variables so that they do not contain duplicates:

```bash
> print $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin
> path+=/sbin
> path+=/sbin
> print $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/sbin:/sbin
> typeset -U PATH path
> print $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/sbin
```

You may also want to look at the `:a` [expansion modifier](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers) to get the absolute path from a relative path.